# How to count number of projects that got approved or the status changed in DAX

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerquery, m

I have a data set that looks like below. The data is about project ideas that are raised in our company. The project ideas will be kept in Backlog section first and then moved to Do Next once then get approved. The modified date is a date when the project idea reviewed and approved or the status changed to Do Next. If it is not approved, then it remains in Backlog.

```
Id      Modified Date   Created Date    Status
1       8/4/2017            8/4/2017    Backlog
2       6/10/2021           6/10/2021   Backlog
3       3/5/2018            3/5/2018    Backlog
1       6/5/2020            8/4/2017    Do Next
1       30/5/2021           3/5/2020    Analyze
2       5/4/2022            6/10/2021   Do Next
2       8/8/2022            6/10/2021   Analyze
```

What I want to achieve is that, I want to count how many projects moved from Backlog to Do Next status using DAX function or approved. So this time, for example I have two projects that moved from Backlog to Do Next (Id1 and Id 2).  I am relatively new to DAX. Can anyone please help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have modified your table to add an "orphan" `Do Next` Status, as the last row, to test the count dependency on the previous Status `Backlog`.

Assuming your table look like this

### Table

| Id | Modified Date | Created Date | Status |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 08 April 2017 | 08 April 2017 | Backlog |
| 2 | 06 October 2021 | 06 October 2021 | Backlog |
| 3 | 03 May 2018 | 03 May 2018 | Backlog |
| 1 | 06 May 2020 | 08 April 2017 | Do Next |
| 1 | 30 May 2021 | 03 May 2020 | Analyze |
| 2 | 05 April 2022 | 06 October 2021 | Do Next |
| 2 | 08 August 2022 | 06 October 2021 | Analyze |
| 4 | 09 August 2022 | 06 October 2021 | Do Next |

### Calculation

```
Count Projects = 
VAR BacklogProjects =
    SUMMARIZE ( FILTER ( 'Table', [Status] = "Backlog" ), [Id] )
VAR DoNextProjects =
    SUMMARIZE ( FILTER ( 'Table', [Status] = "Do Next" ), [Id] )
VAR SameProjects =
    INTERSECT ( BacklogProjects, DoNextProjects )
VAR Result =
    COUNTROWS ( SameProjects )
RETURN
    Result
``
```

Comment: Thank you so much @ Angelo Canepa. That was awesome. In my understanding, what you did here is you are getting the Ids for each status and count the Ids where they are matching right?

Comment: yes, that's correct. `SUMMARIZE` will give you a unique list for each `Status`.